# I don't know what to test to se for working out a correlation

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test

I am researching how canine characteristics affect the length of stay (LOS) in rescue shelters. I have historical data and want to test the correlations. Characteristics I want to measure are: ages (5 groups), 9 breed groups, and coat colour (20 options). The information I have is for 699 dogs, with LOS measured in days ranging from 1 - 375. What test do I need to do? I think it's a chi squared, however I can't get my head round how to start. Should I group the LOS days to groups? Having researched tests, ANOVA seems to come up a lot but I'm not sure. help please!
Thanks,
Rosanna

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given, I infer that you do not have a fully crossed design, meaning that there are combinations of age group, breed group and coat colour for which you have no data.

I would therefore recommend running a separate analysis for your each of your three predictor variables. So you do not need to worry about these missing combinations, on the other hand you will not be able to analyse specific interactions between your predictor variables.

A chi-square test is usually used if you have only categorical variables, but in your case, there is a continuous variable (length of stay). Therefore, ANOVA would be a better fit. For example, to test if length of stay differs between age groups, you can run a one-way ANOVA with age group as predictor variable (independent variable) and length of stay as outcome variable (dependent variable). If you get a significant result, this means that at least one age group is different from the other age groups in terms of length of stay and you can do post-hoc tests to analyse which age groups exactly differ.

Comment: Hi Mesolimbic, That's great, thank you. So doing an ANOVA, how would I set up the table? Using the age group.Would I need to total the number of days for each age group? 1 6-9
1 3-6
1 0-1
2 9+
3 1-3
4 3-6
4 0-1
5 3-6
5 1-3
5 1-3
5 0-1
5 0-1
6 9+
6 9+
6 9+  Snapshot of data I have. Column A is number of days ranging from 1 - 375, Column B is age group. I have 699 in total.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand the data array in your comment. How you arrange the data table might differ depending on where you do your analysis but mostl likely it will look like a table with three rows: some id number, age group, length of stay. You definitely will keep your single cases and not aggregate your data before running the ANOVA

Comment: Sorry, the formatting didn't work too well in my response!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm still really struggling with it but will keep trying!